# Unknown Window class Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode, macos

I recently organized the project folder for my Mac app, which contains over 40 custom classes. I organized these classes by putting them in folders.

After making Xcode aware of the new file locations, I ran my app. The following was logged...

```
Unknown Window class TSDirectoryWindow in Interface Builder file,
 creating generic Window instead
```

I went into the compile sources, removed every file, then added them back (thinking maybe the compiler was still looking at the old locations). No luck.

I'm semi-new to Mac/Objective-C development, and I'm starting to think organizing my files was a bad idea. For all I know, this could be a big no-no. It appears to be a issue with every nib, as I get the same message when `MainMenu` is the main interface,

```
Unknown class 'TSAppDelegate', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path 
/Users/tsilva/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podsnatcher-dlctvrrkdaksfdbblvopdarwlslr/Build/Products/Debug/Podsnatcher.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/MainMenu.nib.
```

Any ideas on how I can get this fixed? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding the files to the linker for the "MyAppTests" target, not the application itself. Whoops.